# Interchanging two essential suprema of a random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes

**Setting**

Let's start with the definition of the essential supremum of a random variable:

> A $\mathcal G$-measurable random variable (rv) $Y$ is called **essential suprema** of a family of $\mathcal G$-measurable rv $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ (with values in $[-\infty,\infty ]$), if
>
> $a)$ $Y\ge X_i$ a.s. for every $i \in I$
>
> $b)$ $Y \le Z$ a.s. for every $\mathcal G$-measurable rv $Z$ with $Z \ge X_i$
>
> We write $Y=: \text{ess sup}_{i \in I} X_i.$

**Question**

I would like to know if the following equality is true or not: Let $I$ and $J$ be too arbitrary index sets and $(X_i^j)_{i\in I, i \in J}$  a bounded family of rvs, then

$$\text{ess sup}_{i \in I} \text{ess sup}_{j\in J} X_i^j \overset{?}=\text{ess sup}_{j \in J} \text{ess sup}_{i \in I} X_i^j.$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is true and it is a direct consequence of the claim proved here: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451847/double-essential-supremum-mathrmess-sup-z-in-x-times-yfx-y-mathrmess). With minor adaptations you can use to prove your claim. 

I would also suggest to have a look at the following post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/simple-question-the-double-supremum) for a proof of this fact for the non-random case.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment! I see how the posts you mentioned are similar to the question I asked but I have still a hard time to how to get my desired equality as a consequence of your first post. Specifically, the definition of the essential supremum of $f$ is different than the definition of the essential supremum of a rv. Would you give me an idea how to start the proof? Thank you!

Comment: I would start the following way: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P), (I, \mathcal I,\mu_I), (J,\mathcal J,\mu_J)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $(\Omega\times I\times J, \sigma(\Omega\times I\times J), \mu)$ be the product measure. Consinder $X:\Omega\times I \times J→\mathbb R$, we write $X(\omega,i,j)=X_i^j(\omega)$ then $$X_i^j\le \text{ess sup}_{(i,j) \in I\times J} X_i^j \quad \text{for } \mu-\text{alomst  every } (\omega,i,j)\in \Omega\times J\times I.$$

Is this a good start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{gather*}
 U_i=\operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{j\in J}X_i^{(j)},\quad \forall i\in I, 
 \qquad  V= \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{i\in I}U_i,\\
 A_i^{(j)}=\{U_i\ge X_i^{(j)}\}, \quad  B_i=\{V\ge U_i\},
\end{gather*}
then
\begin{gather*}
 \mathsf{P}(A_i^{(j)})=1,\qquad \forall j\in J,\quad \forall i\in I, \tag{1}\\
  \mathsf{P}(B_i)=1,\qquad \forall i\in I.  \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
In view of $B_iA_i^{(j)}\subset\{V\ge X_i^{(j)}\} $ and (1),(2),
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(V\ge X_i^{(j)})\ge \mathsf{P}(B_iA_i^{(j)})=1. \qquad   \forall i\in I, \quad \forall j\in J,    \tag{3} 
\end{equation*}
Furthermomre, from (3) and the definition of $ \operatorname{ess\,sup} $,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(V\ge \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{i\in I}X_i^{(j)})=1,\qquad \forall j\in J,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(V\ge \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{j\in J}\,\operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{i\in I}X_i^{(j)})=1.
\end{equation*}
Now, by the symmetry of $ i $ and $ j $ in above proof,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(\operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{i\in I} \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{j\in J} X_i^{(j)} = \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{j\in J} \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{i\in I} X_i^{(j)})=1.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for your response! Just a little question: What do mean by $B_i A_i^{(k)}$? Is it the intersection of $B_i$ and $A_i^{(k)}$, so $B_i A_i^{(k)}=B_i \cap A_i^{(k)}$?

Comment: @Trumpet You are welcome. Yes, $B_iA^{(k)}_i$ is the intersection of $B_i$ and $A^{(k)}_i$.

Comment: Thank you again!